# Llenar un spinner dentro de RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview

Hola cuento con un RecyclerView en el cual quiero colocar un spinner para colocar la cantidad que necesito de un producto así como poder eliminar un ítem.
Agradezco quien me puede orientar ya que no me esta funcionando el spinner.
Estoy manejando una actividad y un adaptador:
1. Este es el código de la actividad.

public class Pedidos extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

```
    private ImageButton iBVolver, borras;

    //private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private DataBaseManager managerCurso;
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    //private ProductoAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;
    private List<Producto> listaItemsCursos;
    private int id_pedido;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedidos);
        MultiDex.install(this);

        iBVolver = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iBVolver);
        iBVolver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent pys = new Intent(Pedidos.this, ServiciosyVeterinarias.class);
                startActivity(pys);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cargando Categorias", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        managerCurso = new DataBaseManager(this);
        listaItemsCursos = managerCurso.getPedidoList();

        // Obtener el Recycler
        recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.pedidos);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // Usar un administrador para LinearLayout
        lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);

        // Crear un nuevo adaptador
        ProductoAdapter adapter = new ProductoAdapter(listaItemsCursos, this);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        recycler.addOnScrollListener(rVOnScrollListener);
        recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recycler.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(Pedidos.this,
                        new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                            }
                        })
        );
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        managerCurso.cerrar();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    // Este método sería comprobar que el desplazamiento recyclerview ha tocado fondo o no///
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)

                /*spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cantidadPedido);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);*/
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Método reemplazado para detectar el desplazamiento//
    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener rVOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
}
```

2. Codigo del adaptador:

```js
public class ProductoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductoAdapter.ProductoViewHolder> {
    //Cargando la imagen y el contexto
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context mainContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    //Para almacenar una lista de todos los Clientes
    List<Producto> items;

    public ProductoAdapter(List<Producto> items, Context contexto) {
        super();
        this.items = items;
        this.mainContext = contexto;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
    }

    @Override
    public ProductoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mostrar_pedido, parent, false);
        ProductoViewHolder pHolder = new ProductoViewHolder(v);
        return pHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductoViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final Producto item = items.get(position);

        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(mainContext).getImageLoader();

        viewHolder.txtpysId.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPysId()));
        viewHolder.iVPyS.setImageUrl(String.valueOf(item.getPysImagen()), imageLoader);
        viewHolder.txtnombre.setText(item.getPysNombre());
        viewHolder.txtdescrip.setText(item.getPysDescripcion());
        viewHolder.txtprecio.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPysPrecio()));
        viewHolder.txtcliNom.setText(item.getTienNombre());
        viewHolder.txtborrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeItem(item);
            }
        });

        viewHolder.txtcant.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, addItem(ites)));

    }

    private void removeItem(Producto item) {
        int currPosition = items.indexOf(item);
        items.remove(currPosition);
        notifyItemRemoved(currPosition);
    }


    private Producto addItem(String ites) {
        addItem("1");
        addItem("2");
        addItem("3");
        addItem("4");
        addItem("5");
        addItem("6");

        return addItem(ites);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ProductoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        protected TextView txtpysId;
        protected NetworkImageView iVPyS;
        ;
        protected TextView txtnombre;
        protected TextView txtdescrip;
        protected TextView txtprecio;
        protected Spinner txtcant;
        ;
        protected TextView txtcliNom;
        protected ImageButton txtborrar;

        public ProductoViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtpysId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pysId);
            iVPyS = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iVPyS);
            txtnombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            txtdescrip = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtVDescripcion);
            txtprecio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
            txtcliNom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tVCliNombre);
            txtborrar = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.borrar);
            txtcant = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: algún error en concreto?, o o simplemente no se llena el spinner?

Comment: Tengo una base de datos ya creada y la cual se muestra en un Recyclerview con valores como Id, Nombre y Telefono y quiero colocar un spinner el cual me deje colocar una serie de valores, como puedo hacer para que cuando le de click en un valor del spinner se guarde dicho valor en SQLite y despues cuando vuelva a entrar a la actividad me muestre el valor guardado, agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedas brindar. Gracias.